# Getting this hidden view state in IE browser

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, viewstate

Getting this thrown in the IE browser while opening up the asp.net application.

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTQ4ODU3MTg5Ng9kFgICAw9kFigCBA9kFgICAQ8UKwACZDwrABwBABYEHhNzZXJBY3RpdmVDZWxsU3RyaW5nZB4Sc2VyQWN0aXZlUm93U3RyaW5nZGQCBg9kFgICAQ8UKwACZDwrABwBABYEHwBkHwFkZAIID2QWAgIBDxQrAAJkPCsAHAEAFgQfAGQfAWRkAg4PFCsABWQ8KwAFAQAWAh4FVmFsdWUFCzAxLUFwci0yMDE4FCsADBYGHgJCMQIyHgFFBS5
```

Can someone shed some light on whats happening here? Seems its working on some machines, but not working on some others.
I've tried clearing cache, cookies etc on the browser but issue persists..any pointers will be helpful

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: hello, i have a asp.net application, while browsing one of the pages from a remote host i'm getting this quoted error thrown in IE browser window and the page doesn't load, it just says hidden view state name and value, any idea what could be going wrong here? its working fine in most other machines, only some machines have this problem.

Comment: Try to post a code from your web page. It can help us to understand the issue in better way. You are talking about ViewState but you are showing the code of Hidden input field. also try to inform us, Which version of IE has this issue. If possible than try to post the snapshot of full error message. We will try to check it and try provide solution to you.